# Why does withCallingHandlers still throw an error?

Tags: r

```
some_f <- function() {
  stop("Error")
}

t2 <- withCallingHandlers({some_f()},
         error=function(err){print("got here")},
         warning=function(warn){return(NULL)})
```

output:

```
[1] "got here"
 Error in some_f() : Error 
3. stop("Error") 
2. some_f() 
1. withCallingHandlers({
      some_f()
   }, error = function(err) {
      print("easldfa") ...
```

The error function is activated because "got here" was printed out. But it still throw an error. It shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: The error function is activated **not** because "got here" was printed out but because you assign `t2` to `some_f` function output that throws an error with a message `Error`. Like in `try-catch`, `withCallingHandlers` in this case will do any action specified inside `error` function call while throwing the `some_f()` function's stop error message. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up `withCallingHandlers` with `tryCatch`.  When you use `withCallingHandlers`, your handler will be called, followed by any others established earlier, i.e. in your example, the default handler for an error condition.

To get the behaviour you expect, use something like this:

```
> some_f <- function() {
+   stop("Error")
+ }
> 
> t2 <- tryCatch({some_f()},
+          error=function(err){print("got here")},
+          warning=function(warn){return(NULL)})
[1] "got here"
```

This will also set `t2` to `"got here"`, because that's the result of the `print()` function.  You could put a different value as the return of that error handler, e.g.

```
> t2 <- tryCatch({some_f()},
+          error=function(err){print("got here"); 123},
+          warning=function(warn){return(NULL)})
[1] "got here"
> t2
[1] 123
```